# Where to put the adjective when asking for something that comes in multiple sizes?

Tags: measure-word, adjectives

This morning in Taipei I went to buy a coffee.

I knew how to say 我要一杯咖啡 and I knew the word for big is 大.

But I didn't know where in the sentence to put the 大. Does it go before 杯 to mean "big cup"? Or if 杯 is a classifier rather than a noun here, I guess it can't take an adjective. Unless it can actually function as both noun and classifier at once?

Or alternatively would it go before 咖啡? That sounds odd when I back-translate literally into English "I want one cup of big coffee". But you can never trust literal translations to be idiomatic anyway.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe: Thanks for fixing my dumb mistake in the title!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a linguist, just a native speaker. My opinion is that 大 should go before 杯, i.e. 我要一大杯咖啡, since I have never heard anyone said 我要一杯大咖啡.

Words like 杯 are called 量词(sorry I don't know the exact term), and the adjectives about amount are always placed before 量词. For example, 
一大碗饭= a bowl of a lot of rice， 一大把花= a bunch of many flowers.

Maybe this solution is not satisfying; sorry I can't explain it in detail. 量词 is actually quite sophisticated, and is often omitted when translated into English. I hope [this article](https://m.douban.com/group/topic/8930200/) will help (well it's written in Chinese).

Comment: Wow, I'm back in Taiwan and just asked my host and she said this way sounds childish or sounds like I want a gigantic cup. She gave me the same answer that [Cristophe](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/20774/164) gives.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I've used

> 我要一杯咖啡，大的。
>
> 我要一杯咖啡，大杯。

I don't know if it's the best way to say it, but I've never had any problem being understood this way...

Answer (score 1):

The adjective is always placed directly before the noun, so it is correct to phrase the sentence as: 
(我)(要)(一杯)(大)(咖啡 )
(I)(want)(a cup of )(**large**)(**coffee**)

- (a cup of) is the quantity word and classifier,
- 大 in 大咖啡 is short for "大杯 / 大碼" (large cup/ large size ), it is still functioning as an adjective, but the phrase 大杯咖啡 / 大碼咖啡 is treated as one item on the menu, so you can call it a noun.

Edit:

> so, 一大杯咖啡 or 餃子一小份 is incorrect then?

It is not incorrect, the adjective is just modifying different objects in the phrases:

1. 一**大杯**咖啡 (one **large cup** of coffee); 一**小份**餃子 (one **small order** of dumplings)
2. 一杯**大咖啡** (one cup of **large coffee**); 一份**小餃子** (one order of **small dumpling(s)**)
3. **大咖啡**一杯 (**large coffee**, one cup); **小餃子**一份 (**small dumpling(s)**, one order)
4. 咖啡一**大杯** (coffee, one **large cup**); 餃子一**小份** (dumplings, one **small order**)

小 in 小餃子 can be the adjective (small) that modify the noun 餃子(dumpling), meaning "the size of individual dumpling is small; it can also be shorthand for 小份, "小(份)餃子" = "small (order of) dumplings", meaning the number of dumplings is small.

Comment: After I posted the question here I kept Googling and one site, I think English WIkipedia, said that when the number is 一 there is a special case and the adjective can actually come either before or after the classifier. Is that true? By the way words don't really have a "front" and many people would interpret "in front of" to mean "before", so it's clearer in English to write "before" or "after".

Comment: I don't think there's any exception regarding the order of adjective and noun in Chinese grammar. But a classifier can be placed before or after a noun, for example --  一杯大碼咖啡 (a cup of large coffee) = 大碼咖啡一杯(large coffee, one cup)

Comment: Wouldn't 大碼 be considered "adjective+noun" here or would it be an adjective phrase? Apologies for being such a newbie!

Comment: 大= large, 碼=size, it is an adjective phrase for " large-sized"

Comment: So, is 一大杯咖啡 or 餃子一小份 incorrect？！@TangHo I keep hearing these every day!

Comment: "One cup of large coffee" may be grammatically correct but it sounds strange in English, and judging by luisedec's answer 我要一杯大咖啡 is strange in Chinese - louisedec, a native speaker, never heard anyone use it.